# In which segment is shstrtable?

Tags: elf, sections, segment

I'm working with elf64 files and i was wondering two things, the first is, in which segment the shstrtable is stored, because reviewing readelf -l doesn't appear. And the other question (coming from the first one) is it possible for a section not be inside a segment?

Also i noticed some 'gaps' between some segments. What is inside those gaps?

I am using the following example, that is an hello_world.c:

```
readelf -lW hello                                          

El tipo del fichero elf es DYN (Fichero objeto compartido)
Entry point 0x1040
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 64

Encabezados de Programa:
  Tipo           Desplaz  DirVirt            DirFísica          TamFich  TamMem   Opt Alin
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x000268 0x000268 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x0002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000560 0x000560 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0001e5 0x0001e5 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x000118 0x000118 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x000248 0x000250 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002df8 0x0000000000003df8 0x0000000000003df8 0x0001e0 0x0001e0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00200c 0x000000000000200c 0x000000000000200c 0x000034 0x000034 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x0000000000003de8 0x000218 0x000218 R   0x1

 mapeo de Sección a Segmento:
  Segmento Secciones...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt 
   03     .init .plt .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   06     .dynamic 
   07     .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag 
   08     .eh_frame_hdr 
   09     
   10     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in which segment the shstrtable is stored, because reviewing readelf -l doesn't appear.

It doesn't appear in any segment.

> And the other question (coming from the first one) is it possible for a section not be inside a segment?

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65866059/50617).

> Also i noticed some 'gaps' between some segments. What is inside those gaps?

Nothing. Segments tell the kernel or the runtime loader how to `mmap` the on-disk binary into memory. Since `mmap` operates on whole pages (4096 bytes here), the contents of memory between `0x560` and `0xFFF` will be "whatever happens to be in the file at offsets `0x560` through `0xFFF`, but the program shouldn't access it and the contents is effectively undefined. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888474/50617).

Comment: Thank you so much, everything is more clear now. But the answer you linked creates two more questions:

the column align should not be always 4096 bytes (0x1000)?

I don't understand clearly what is said in the first linked answer: `The final linked file is not required to have any sections at all (only segments matter at runtime)`

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez The `LOAD` segments are the ones that will be `mmap`ed, and they _are_ aligned on `0x1000`. Sorry I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Don't worry about the other question, i figured out myself, thank you so much.