# Why ELF's segments aren't contiguous?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I've read this [infect.c](https://github.com/BR903/ELFkickers/blob/master/infect/infect.c) source which demonstrates how to infect ELF file with a malicious entry point.

It proceeds like this :

1. Load an executable file into memory
2. Find a suitable segment to extend with the payload
3. Update the payload to jump the original entry point location
4. Update the entry point to jump the payload location
5. Extend the segment with the malicious payload

Here is how it discover the suitable phdr :

```
static int findinfectionphdr(Elf64_Phdr const *phdr, int count)
{
    Elf64_Off pos, endpos;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i) {
    if (phdr[i].p_filesz > 0 && phdr[i].p_filesz == phdr[i].p_memsz
                 && (phdr[i].p_flags & PF_X)) {
        pos = phdr[i].p_offset + phdr[i].p_filesz;
        endpos = pos + sizeof infection;
        for (j = 0 ; j < count ; ++j) {
        if (phdr[j].p_offset >= pos && phdr[j].p_offset < endpos
                        && phdr[j].p_filesz > 0)
            break;
        }
        if (j == count)
        return i;
    }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The first loop looks for an executable segment to infect and the second test if there is any other segment susceptible to overlap the infected one.

If all the segments were contiguous this infection could not be performed.

So here is my question : why compilers don't produce contiguous segments in ELF files ?
Or alternatively : what justifies the gap between them ?

Answer (score 0):

> what justifies the gap between them ?

The segments are `mmap`ed into memory. `mmap` can only perform mappings in terms of *whole pages*. Therefore, you can not have an executable segment which ends in the middle of a page and a non-executable segment which follows it without a gap.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888474/50617).