# Why are there overlapping and misaligned segments in a simple ELF binary?

Tags: c, linux, linker, clang, elf

I am writing an ELF loader and studying the ELF format. I have a simple hello world binary that I created using Clang 16 in Fedora 38, it works and I’ve not compiled\linked with any specific options (`clang hello.c -o hello`). I examined the program headers with `readelf` and found something that doesn’t line up with my understanding of the LOAD and DYNAMIC headers.

For example:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
…
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000004f0 0x00000000000004f0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000
                 0x000000000000016d 0x000000000000016d  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000
                 0x00000000000000dc 0x00000000000000dc  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002df8 0x0000000000403df8 0x0000000000403df8
                 0x0000000000000214 0x0000000000000218  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002e08 0x0000000000403e08 0x0000000000403e08
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     0x8
```

There are two issues that I can’t wrap my head around. Notice how the first three LOAD headers have aligned virtual addresses, this makes sense to me. But the last LOAD header and DYNAMIC header overlap and are misaligned. The executable gets loaded just fine in Linux, but Linux also seems to be accounting for this. Here is the `/proc/<pid>/maps`:

```
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 00:23 16905823                         /path/to/hello
00401000-00402000 r-xp 00001000 00:23 16905823                         /path/to/hello
00402000-00403000 r--p 00002000 00:23 16905823                         /path/to/hello
00403000-00404000 r--p 00002000 00:23 16905823                         /path/to/hello
00404000-00405000 rw-p 00003000 00:23 16905823                         /path/to/hello
```

So I have a few questions:

- Why does my linker produce misaligned segments? It seems like a bad idea to rely on the OS to fix the alignment.
- Why does my linker create overlapping segments? Again, it seems like a bad idea to rely on the OS to fix this.
- Is there a specific convention, standard, or algorithm that Linux implements to correct for this? It feels like there is some undocumented behavior here or documented behavior that I haven’t been able to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does my linker produce misaligned segments?

It doesn't. The requirement is that it should be possible to `mmap` the `LOAD` segments directly, and for that, the following *must* be true: `p_vaddr % pagesize == p_offset % pagesize`. That is true for all the `LOAD` segments in your output.

> Why does my linker create overlapping segments?

There is nothing wrong with that -- the same file contents will appear in memory twice.

The alternative would be to insert a large hole into the file, wasting disk space.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888474/50617).

> Is there a specific convention, standard, or algorithm that Linux implements to correct for this?

No correction is needed. Read [man mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) carefully.

Since the `offset` must be page-aligned, the dynamic loader rounds down *both* `p_vaddr` and `p_offset` to be page aligned, and performs `mmap(..., MAP_FIXED, ...)` using the page-aligned values for both. That "overmaps" a little bit of data, but guarantees that the code or data ends up at exactly the address it was linked at.

**Update:**

> why the linker wouldn’t always set p_offset and p_vaddr to the actual values used at runtime

In general this isn't done because the static linker doesn't know the page size at runtime. On `x86_64`, `pagesize` could be 4KiB, 2MiB or 1GiB.

However this particular binary is linked with `0x1000` (4KiB) alignment, so the (static) linker *could have* set `.p_vaddar` and `.p_offset` to their rounded-down values (and adjusted `.p_memsize` up to compensate). The code in the static linker is agnostic to alignment and page size, so it didn't treat the 4KiB as *special* (an entirely reasonable approach).

Comment: Your answers make sense to me, but I’m still confused as to why the linker wouldn’t always set `p_offset` and `p_vaddr` to the actual values used at runtime unless the ELF type is `ET_DYN`. It would make it clearer IMO without the extra math.